# Regex contains at least 1 character except space, then space, then at least 1 character except space, then any number of any characters

Tags: regex

I need a regex which matches rule in the title.
Valid examples:

```
a b
<script> <
Kim John Un
Bobbie 27
```

Invalid examples:

```
ab
Arrrr
232
Bobbie27
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope it will help you to learn something about regex:

```
^[^ ]+ [^ ].*$
```

If there are new lines use this one:

```
^[^\s]+ [^\s].*$
```

Comment: Thanks, Egan! Works for me. How can I allow any number of spaces in the middle?

Comment: add a `\s+` in middle

Answer (score 2):

You have to check for non-spaces seperated by a space.

```
^[^\s]+\s[^\s]+(.)*$
```

1. `^` start point
2. `[^\s]+` accept anything except space
3. `\s` space
4. `$` End point
5. (.)* to match any characters after that.

Working example in JavaScript

```js
var re = /^[^\s]+\s[^\s]+(.)*$/;

console.log("a b",re.test("a b"));
console.log("<script> <",re.test("<script> <"));
console.log("Kim John Un",re.test("Kim John Un"));
console.log("Bobbie 27",re.test("Bobbie 27"));

console.log("ab",re.test("ab"));
console.log("Arrrr",re.test("Arrrr"));
console.log("232",re.test("232"));
console.log("Bobbie27",re.test("Bobbie27"));
```

Comment: @max I am suggesting you to accept the other answer because Egan is first to answer

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using the regex

```
^[^ ]+ [^ ].*$
```

see the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/rvDLBN/1)